# How to capture screenshot when I am running selinium python (robotframework) headless mode using xvfb library in centos

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, centos, robotframework, xvfb

I am running my python selinium script using robotframework.
I configure xvfb library to run my script in headless mode.
Script is running properly but whatever screenshot it is capturing is blank.